# Trying to use classes to keep my code clean - not working

Tags: javascript, class, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I keep getting this error and I'm absolutely stumped as to what to do:

```
TypeError: Visas.list is not a function
at /Users/name/Sites/chatbot/functions/index.js:72:28
```

Am I missing anything? I tried adding imports with `type:method` in my package.json and it blew up on me - will only let me use require.

**index.js**

```
const Visas = require("./src/controllers/visas");

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const database = admin.firestore();

exports.visas = functions.https.onRequest((req,res) => {
    switch (req.method) {
        case 'GET':
            res.send(Visas.list());
            break;
        case 'PUT':
            res.status(403).send('Forbidden!');
            break;
        default:
            res.status(405).send({error: 'Something blew up!'});
            break;
    }
});
```

**visas.js**

```
class Visas {

    static list() {
        let requirementsData = database.collection('requirements');
        const travelData = requirementsData.doc(req.params.country);

        travelData.get()
            .then(doc => {
                if (!doc.exists) {
                    return res.status(404).send("Can't find a record for this country.");
                } else {
                    const docData = doc.data(),
                        visas = docData.visas;

                    return res.send(visas);
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return res.send('Error getting document' + err);
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to export `Visas` from visas.js if you want to use it after requiring it.  nodejs uses commonjs module syntax.  Add this to the end of visas.js:

```
module.exports = Visas
```

Comment: This goes in the index.js or visas.js?

Comment: Edited the answer